# save exec() output to file in

Tags: php, shell, debian, exec, gzip

I am executing `gzip` on a debian server via php using the `exec()` function.

```
gzip -1 -c file1.xxx > file1.gz
```

Now I want to errors to be saved in some error.log.

1. How I can set output to file?
2. Is it better to use `shell_exec()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to redirect `stderr` to a file, use the `2>` redirector (`2` is the file-handle for the stderr):

```
gzip -1 -c file1.xxx >file1.gz  2>error.log
```

(see also the *REDIRECTION* section `man bash`)

Comment: Thx. I was trying this exacly this way but i have'n permissions on file... Is there posibility save to error.log executed command?

Comment: And in error.log is a lack of information... When i run command for ex. `nonsense 2>&1` i got in browser -> sh: 1: nonsense: not found but if i run `nonsense 2>error.log` in error log is -> sh: 1: bad: not found...